# Как сохранить изображение?

Tags: php

По GET через cURL получаю изображение:

```
curl('https://site.ru/image');
```

На странице у меня оно отображается:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$img = curl('https://site.ru/image');
echo $img;
```

А как его сохранить на сервере, и задать ему имя, например `name.jpg` ?
и до сохранения изменить ширину и высоту изображения. либо чтобы ширина была, например 240, а высота автоматически подгонялась?

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$img = curl('https://site.ru/image');
$fp = fopen('image.jpg','x');
fwrite($fp, $img);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: а можно ли как-то еще до его сохранения изменить ширину и высоту изображения? либо чтобы ширина была, например 240, а высота автоматически подгонялась?

Comment: можно, запрос в гугл php image resize даст вам ответ :)